# How do I store the result of a query inside a temporary table in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am trying to store the results of a complex query inside a temporary table but I keep getting an error. Below is the code from my stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @TempItems TABLE
(
ID int IDENTITY, ForumThreadID int, ForumID int, ParentID int, title NVARCHAR(MAX), title_path NVARCHAR(MAX), 
level_id NVARCHAR(MAX), level_id_path NVARCHAR(MAX), PostBody NVARCHAR(MAX), CreatedBy int, UserName NVARCHAR(50), Created DateTime
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'WITH TreeList (ForumThreadID, ForumID, ParentID, title, title_path, level_id, level_id_path) as 
    ( 
    SELECT p.ForumThreadID,  
    p.ForumID, 
    p.ParentID,  
    p.PostSubject,  
    CONVERT(nvarchar(max), p.ForumThreadID),  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY p.ForumThreadID),  
    RIGHT(''0000'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY p.ForumThreadID) AS varchar(max)),4)  
    FROM ForumThreads p 
    WHERE (p.ParentID = ' + @ParentID + ') AND (p.Deleted IS NULL) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT c.ForumThreadID,  
    c.ForumID,  
    c.ParentID,  
    c.PostSubject,  
    r.title_path + ''/'' + CAST(c.ForumThreadID AS VARCHAR(MAX)),  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ParentID ORDER BY c.ForumThreadID),  
    CONVERT(varchar(max), r.level_id_path + ''.'' + RIGHT(''0000'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ParentID ORDER BY c.ForumThreadID) AS VARCHAR),4))  
    FROM ForumThreads AS c 
    INNER JOIN treelist AS r 
    ON c.ParentID = r.ForumThreadID 
    WHERE (c.Deleted IS NULL)) 
    SELECT TOP 100 TreeList.*, d.PostBody, d.CreatedBy, Members.UserName, COALESCE(d.Created,''1-JAN-1900'') AS Created 
    FROM TreeList INNER JOIN ForumThreads AS d ON TreeList.ForumThreadID = d.ForumThreadID INNER JOIN 
    Members ON d.CreatedBy = Members.MemberID 
    WHERE (d.Deleted IS NULL) 
    ORDER BY level_id_path;'

INSERT INTO @TempItems (ForumThreadID, ForumID, ParentID, title, title_path, level_id, level_id_path, PostBody, CreatedBy, UserName, Created) EXEC @SQL

SELECT * FROM @TempItems
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure spPagedForumThreads, Line 53
The name 'WITH TreeList (ForumThreadID, ForumID, ParentID, title, title_path, level_id, level_id_path) as 
( 
SELECT p.ForumThreadID,  
p.ForumID, 
p.ParentID,  
p.PostSubject,  
CONVERT(nvarchar(max), p.ForumThreadID),  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY p.ForumThreadID),  
RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY p.ForumThreadID) AS varchar(max)),4)  
FROM ForumThreads p 
WHERE (p.ParentID = 10720) AND (p.Deleted IS NULL) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT c.ForumThreadID,  
c.ForumID,  
c.ParentID,  
c.PostSubject,  
r.title_path + '/' + ' is not a valid identifier.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there another way to create a temporary table, one that does not require saving the query as a string?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what version you're on, so you might need to use a #temp table instead of a table variable (can't be target of insert/exec), but [did you try `EXEC(@SQL)`? The parentheses are important.](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx) Where did you ever see working syntax that just had `EXEC @sql`?

Comment: Try putting a semi colon in front of the WITH.

Comment: Indeed, the missing semicolon and parentheses were part of the problem. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What purpose does executing dynamic SQL serve?  After your CTE, you should just be able to modify your `SELECT` statement to be `INSERT INTO @TempItems SELECT TOP 100 TreeList.* .....`

This should just work without needing dynamic SQL (i.e. `EXEC`).  Note the statement prior to the `WITH` needs to be terminated with a semi-colon in order to be syntactically valid.

```
DECLARE @TempItems TABLE
(
ID int IDENTITY, ForumThreadID int, ForumID int, ParentID int, title NVARCHAR(MAX), title_path NVARCHAR(MAX), 
level_id NVARCHAR(MAX), level_id_path NVARCHAR(MAX), PostBody NVARCHAR(MAX), CreatedBy int, UserName NVARCHAR(50), Created DateTime
);

WITH TreeList (ForumThreadID, ForumID, ParentID, title, title_path, level_id, level_id_path) as 
    ( 
    SELECT p.ForumThreadID,  
    p.ForumID, 
    p.ParentID,  
    p.PostSubject,  
    CONVERT(nvarchar(max), p.ForumThreadID),  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY p.ForumThreadID),  
    RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY p.ForumThreadID) AS varchar(max)),4)  
    FROM ForumThreads p 
    WHERE (p.ParentID = ' + @ParentID + ') AND (p.Deleted IS NULL) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT c.ForumThreadID,  
    c.ForumID,  
    c.ParentID,  
    c.PostSubject,  
    r.title_path + '/' + CAST(c.ForumThreadID AS VARCHAR(MAX)),  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ParentID ORDER BY c.ForumThreadID),  
    CONVERT(varchar(max), r.level_id_path + '.' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ParentID ORDER BY c.ForumThreadID) AS VARCHAR),4))  
    FROM ForumThreads AS c 
    INNER JOIN treelist AS r 
    ON c.ParentID = r.ForumThreadID 
    WHERE (c.Deleted IS NULL)) 

INSERT INTO @TempItems (ForumThreadID, ForumID, ParentID, title, title_path, level_id, level_id_path, PostBody, CreatedBy, UserName, Created)
    SELECT TOP 100 TreeList.*, d.PostBody, d.CreatedBy, Members.UserName, COALESCE(d.Created,'1-JAN-1900') AS Created 
    FROM TreeList INNER JOIN ForumThreads AS d ON TreeList.ForumThreadID = d.ForumThreadID INNER JOIN 
    Members ON d.CreatedBy = Members.MemberID 
    WHERE (d.Deleted IS NULL) 
    ORDER BY level_id_path;


SELECT * FROM @TempItems
```

Comment: Thanks! I got that code from somewhere else and modified it for my needs without fully grasping how it works. Now I am closer to understanding CTEs. Had to make a slight modification to your suggested code and replaced `' + @ParentID + '` with `@ParentID`. I believe that was a remnant from where I tried saving the query into a string for later execution.

Comment: Would I be correct if I said that using the WITH statement is like creating a temp table?

Answer (score 0):

`EXEC(@SQL)` instead of just `EXEC @SQL`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the parentheses were missing and adding them solved parts of the problem.